# Joomla3 editor removing inline css

Tags: css, joomla3.0

I have an article in a Joomla 3 theme where I want to add inline CSS to the article but upon saving the file, the CSS automatically disappears from the article. I am sensing that there is some sort of purifier that is doing this but I'm pretty new to Joomla so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using default editor or a third party editor like JCE editor?

Comment: Inline css in which element? iframe maybe? One fast solution btw is to use No editor option in your preferences. One other solution is to find the editor plugin in plugin manager and from its options you maybe see why your css is getting stripped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you can write your CSS code in template file for ex, in temlate.css file and all your require class and id pass into your article code.